# Scala, ZIO, Kafka - how to add Producer layer to scope

Tags: scala, zio, zio-kafka

I have a class which produces messages to `Kafka` (using `zio-kafka`):

```
case class MyObject(name: String, otherObject: OtherObject)

class MyProducer(config: KafkaConfiguration) {
   val layer: ZLayer[Any, Throwable, Producer] = config.layer() //it creates layer

  def produceEvent(e: MyObject): RIO[Producer, Unit] = {
    val message = new ProducerRecord(topic, e)
Producer.produce(message, Serde.int, Serde.Json).unit
}

}


object MyProducer {
  val layer: ZLayer[SomeConfig, Throwable, MyProducer] = ZLayer(for { ... } yield new MyProducer(config)
}
```

And now I would like to use this `produceEvent` method in other place:

```
class A(producer: MyProducer) {
  def doSmth(): ZIO[Producer, Throwable, Unit] {

   for {
    // some logic 
    _ <- producer.produceEvent(event)

   } yield ()
   
  } 
}
```

The problem is at runtime I got an error:

```
Defect in zio.Environment: Could not find Producer inside Environment
```

I have no idea how to provide `Producer` to scope. I provided `MyProducer` correctly, but then I need to return `ZIO[Producer, Throwable, Unit]` . Maybe there is other solution to "cut" this Producer from environment and just return `Task[Unit]`?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it makes sense to keep the `Producer` local to `MyProducer`.

You can "provide" it right away:

```scala
def produceEvent(e: MyObject): IO[Unit] = {
  val message = new ProducerRecord(topic, e)
  Producer.produce(message, Serde.int, Serde.Json)
    .unit
    .provide(layer)
}
```

Comment: There is still problem and I nned to provide this Producer through layer here `class MyProducer(p: Producer, config: KafkaConfiguration)`

Comment: You don't. At least not in your original code. The `Producer` can be entirely local to the `MyClass` class. It doesn't have to be injected. Because it's likely not a "global" value that you'd want to share with other classes.